# display data in liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm looking to display information from a csv file on a jekyll-generated site. I need to search for the appropriate category in the csv file, then display four of them on the page. Filtering to the selected category is no problem, but I'm having difficulty limiting the output to four.

Is there a way to apply a limit to an if statement? Or is there any other way to write this? I'm not that savvy in Liquid, so it's extremely likely that I'm missing an obvious solution.

Basic code to make all the applicable data show up on the screen:

```
      {% for study in site.data.studies %}
        {% if study.category contains "foo" %}
            <div class="col-sm-3">

              <h3>{{ study.title }}</h3>
              <div class="list-of-attributes">

                <h6>Attributes: </h6>
                {{ study.attributes }}
              </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}    
            {% continue %}
        {% endif %}

      {% endfor %}
```

I've also tried `unless` and `tablerow`, neither of which worked at all. Am I at least on the right track? How can I limit this forloop to stop at four items?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally data should be filtered before rendering however you can also create a [variable in liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/) to hold the number of stuff rendered

```
{% assign rendered = 0 %}

{% for study in site.data.studies %}
  {% if study.category contains "foo" %}
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h3>{{ study.title }}</h3>
        <div class="list-of-attributes">

          <h6>attributes: </h6>
          {{ study.attributes }}
        </div>
      </div>

    {% assign rendered = rendered | plus: 1 %}
    {% if rendered == 4 %}
      {% break %}
    {% endif %}

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The ideal solution as I said would be to create your own filter which does all the work (filter by category and limit the number of results)

```
{% assign filtered = site.data.studies | my_custom_filter %}
{% for study in filtered %}
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h3>{{ study.title }}</h3>
    <div class="list-of-attributes">
      <h6>attributes: </h6>
      {{ study.attributes }}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think `{% assign rendered = rendered | plus: 1 %}` is better than `{% assign rendered = rendered + 1 %}` that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DavidJacquel!

Comment: This is great, thank you! I had been trying something similar, but wasn't quite getting it - and now that I see your solution, I understand what I was doing wrong. Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that your `category` is a string, not an array, you can do :

```
{% assign selected = site.data.studies | where: 'category','foo' %}
{% for study in selected limit:4 %}
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h3>{{ study.title }}</h3>
    <div class="list-of-attributes">
      <h6>Attributes: </h6>
      {{ study.attributes }}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And if your `category` is a string like `"foo, bar, baz"` or and array of strings you can use the jekyll 3.2 `where_exp` filter like this :

```
{% assign selected = site.data.studies | where_exp:"item", "item.category contains 'foo'" %}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: the data file's category contains multiple strings, so it may read "foo, bar, unicorn" - or it may read "bar, unicorn, foo". So I needed to use `contains` rather than setting a variable and then pulling from that. But thank you!